# Java: Wildcard type vs plain type

Tags: java

A method `eat()` uses a parameter of type `Food`, while `Food` is a generic class:

```
class Food<T> {
    T type; 
    ...
}


class Human {
    public void eat Food(Food food) {
        // eat, eat, and eat, however it has nothing to do with T
    }
}
```

The question is, should I declare `Food<?>` instead of `Food` in `eat`'s parameter? Are there any difference while the method `eat` doesn't care and use anything related with `T`?

Comment: Why are you using generics?

Comment: What are those `type`s of `Food`?

Comment: Are generics really what you want here? Maybe try mkaing `Food` an interface, and use specific implementations if needed required.

Comment: Maybe you currently don't care that `T` could be any type of object. All you need is the toString() or something like that. But it could be useful to establish a base FoodType (Interface). So, if you later do need assumptions that should be common to every FoodType, then those will be guaranteed to be in place.

Comment: The difference is that with `Food food` you can assign anything you like to `food.type`, e.g. a `String`, an `Integer`, a `Frobnitz`. If the value you pass the method as a parameter is, say a `Food<SomethingElse>`, that will (may) lead to a problem later (specifically, a `ClassCastException`). `Food<?> food` prevents this. Raw types: stay away.

Answer (score 0):

If you use just `Food`, then you're using a raw type. The compiler will issue a warning, since it loses any information and cannot do any type checks on subsequent uses of this type.
So if you don't care about `T` inside the method, use `Food<?>` and let the compiler know about this fact.